# Is Normalize.css/Reset CSS included in Angular/React/Vue.js?

Tags: css, angular, reactjs, vue.js, normalize-css

Whenever working with modern Single Page Applications (SPAs) JavaScript frameworks such as Angular/React/Vue.js is it still necessary to include Normalize.css and/or Reset CSS?

Do the frameworks remove all built-in browser stylings (Reset CSS) and make build-in browser styling consistent across browsers (Normalize.css) by default?

Comment: No, they do not. As a matter of fact, you don't get any styling out of the box with `Angular`, `React`, and/or `Vue.js` - they are `JavaScript` frameworks for building frontend UIs. It is up to you how you decide to style them with custom `CSS`, `normalize.css` and/or `reset.css`.

Comment: Nope. They don’t ship with normalize or reset, but i haven’t used either of them for years anyway. They’re less important in the modern browser environment but if you like it, then go right ahead

Comment: @bryan60 I'd still reach out for something like `normalize.css` even though I am dealing with modern browsers - not all are rendering things the same exact way. Also, if you're using some popular UI design system, such as `Material-UI`, they already include the stylesheets needed to "normalize" the look between different browsers, so no need to worry about that.

Comment: @goto1 it could be the case that the frameworks itself not, but actually on top of them we're (almost) always including some UI components (e.g. Material Design) and these libraries would have Normalize.css/Reset CSS included I believe?

Comment: @DanielDanielecki yes, `Material-UI` for example provides `CSS Baseline` - https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/. `JavaScript` libraries/frameworks you've mentioned are used for "different" purposes and not styling your application.